# javascript not working when trying to disable radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

why does my js not working, what i have missed?
im trying to make disable radio when i click my radio
but its not working

hope someone would help me here
thank you

```js
  function tester() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
      if (document.forms[0].elements[i].name == "optradio1") {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[i].value == "pinjdn") {
          if (document.forms[0].elements[i].checked == true) {

            document.forms[0].soptradio[0].disabled = true;
            document.forms[0].soptradio[1].disabled = true;
            document.forms[0].soptradio[2].disabled = true;
            document.forms[0].soptradio[3].disabled = true;
          }
        } else if (document.forms[0].elements[i].value == "hibahln") {
          if (document.forms[0].elements[i].checked == true) {
            document.forms[0].soptradio[0].disabled = false;
            document.forms[0].soptradio[1].disabled = false;
            document.forms[0].soptradio[2].disabled = false;
            document.forms[0].soptradio[3].disabled = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 well">
  <div class="row">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Beban</th>
          <th>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="rm" id="hide">RM</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="pinjln" id="show">Pinj LN</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="localcost" id="show2">Local Cost</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="pnbp" id="hide2">PNBP</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="pinjdn" id="show3" onClick="tester()">Pinj DN</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="hibahdn" id="hide3">Hibah DN</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="hibahln" id="show4" onClick="tester()">Hibah LN</label>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="abc">
      <div class="col-sm-12">


        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
              <div class="radio">
                <th>Jenis Bantuan</th>
                <th>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="soptradio">Pinjaman Valas</label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="soptradio" checked>Pinj. RPLN</label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="soptradio">Hibah Valas</label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="soptradio">Hibah RPLN</label>
                </th>
              </div>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

that's my code
please help me

hope my explanation's clear to everyone

thank you

Comment: When I run the snippet I see these error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: tester is not defined".

Seems like your function is not seemed. Try to put it in `<head>`

Comment: Note, both `form` elements have same value for `name` attribute, `"form1"`. `input` elements which have `name` `"soptradio"` are child elements of  `document.forms[1]`, not `document.forms[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to Forms[1](second form) while disabling. Please see the changed code below:

```js
     function tester()
     {
    for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].elements.length;i++)
      {
        if(document.forms[0].elements[i].name=="optradio1")
        {
         if(document.forms[0].elements[i].value=="pinjdn")
         {
           if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked==true){
     
            document.forms[1].soptradio[0].disabled=true;
            document.forms[1].soptradio[1].disabled=true;
            document.forms[1].soptradio[2].disabled=true;
       document.forms[1].soptradio[3].disabled=true;
           }
         }
          else if(document.forms[0].elements[i].value=="hibahln")
         {
           if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked==true){
            document.forms[1].soptradio[0].disabled=false;
            document.forms[1].soptradio[1].disabled=false;
            document.forms[1].soptradio[2].disabled=false;
       document.forms[1].soptradio[3].disabled=false;
     }
     }
    }
    }
     }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 well">
        <div class="row">
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Beban
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="rm" id="hide">RM</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="pinjln" id="show">Pinj LN</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="localcost" id="show2">Local Cost</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="pnbp" id="hide2">PNBP</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="pinjdn" id="show3" onclick="tester()">Pinj
                            DN</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="hibahdn" id="hide3">Hibah DN</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="hibahln" id="show4" onclick="tester()">Hibah
                            LN</label>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="abc">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <th>
                                    Jenis Bantuan
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="soptradio">Pinjaman Valas</label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="soptradio" checked>Pinj. RPLN</label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="soptradio">Hibah Valas</label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="soptradio">Hibah RPLN</label>
                                </th>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```